# multiply the price and the number of days after getting the difference of two dates

Tags: javascript, html

```
function GetDays()
{
  var dropdt = new Date(document.getElementById("drop_off").value);
  var pickdt = new Date(document.getElementById("pick_up").value);
  return parseInt((dropdt - pickdt) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
}

function cal()
{
  if(document.getElementById("date1"))
  {
    document.getElementById("numdays2").value=GetDays();
  }
}
/*I just get this code also*/
```

I just badly need your help on how to multiply the price from html and the number of days after getting the difference of two dates from javascript. So, I have a fixed price from my html and after displaying the number of days I want to get the total of numberofDays*price.

Comment: no you have the number of days?

Comment: number of days * price

Comment: Hello, please share your code, and explain briefly

Comment: how is your price placed in html? Are you not able to extract price form html or not able to calculate no. of days?

Comment: @AnkitChaudhary the thing is its more of like booking website which I want to display the total cost between two dates multiplied by 2500,its price. For example, the user pick the single room which cost of 2500 and pick the date now and tom. I want to display the total cost on my html page. I hope you understand me, and thank you for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `valueAsDate` of date input to get a date object directly instead of converting its value into date.

```js
function GetDays()
{
  var dropdt = document.getElementById("drop_off").valueAsDate;
  var pickdt = document.getElementById("pick_up").valueAsDate;
  return parseInt((dropdt - pickdt) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
}

function cal()
{
  document.getElementById('value').innerHTML=GetDays()*parseInt(document.getElementById('price').innerHTML);
}
```

```html
Pick Up Date: <input type="date" id="pick_up" ><br/>
Drop Off Date:   <input type="date" id="drop_off"><br/>
Price <span id='price'>50</price><br/>
<button onclick="cal()">Calculate</button><br/>
Total Value <span id='value'></span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This would really help.

Comment: Good to know that @LaraJanePedrigal. Could you accept the answer if it helped to solve your problem

Comment: how can I also display the number of days  ?

Comment: using `innerHTML`  E.g.: <yourElement>.innerHTML=5;

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Calculate(){
let date1 = new Date(document.getElementById("date1").value);
let  date2 = new Date(document.getElementById("date2").value);
let differenceTime = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
let differenceDays = Math.ceil(differenceTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
let result = differenceDays * 50;
console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<input type='date' id='date1'/>
<input type='date' id='date2'/>
<button onclick="Calculate()">
Calculate
</button>
```

Comment: my date was from the html <input type="date">  can I just change the fixed date by getting the elementbyId ?

Comment: try the snippet i modified with an working example. I put 50 as price value just for example. hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, dude. What a big help. Have a nice day.